# PHP running out of memory when uploading to s3 bucket - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2 I'm trying to upload a file to an AWS s3 bucket using the storage facade:

```
    $file = Input::file('file');

    Storage::put('filename', file_get_contents($file));
```

But I'm getting the error message:

```
FatalErrorException in RequestException.php line 107:
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47696229 bytes)
```

The filesize is within the allowerd memory size, and regardless if I increase the allowed memory size in php.ini it still throws the same error.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Add this to php.ini "ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');" and see if it works?

Comment: doesn't matter. you're loading the file and passing it as a string. that means the ENTIRE file is loaded into memory. depending on what happens inside that put() call, multiple COPIES of that string can be created as well, meaning the memory overhead is far higher than just whatever the size of that file is.

Comment: @error2007s I added  "ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');"  to php.ini and my webserver crashed.

Comment: Then your php is causing a memory leak which send the CPU utilization to 100% and crashes the web server. You need to find the code that is causing the memory leak

Comment: Basicly the file is so large it does not fit into the memory. Only thing you can do is send the file in chunks instead of trying to load it at once into the memory. People don't care about memory nowadays, God bring good ol' C days back.

Comment: @Piyush Patil  Your advice sucks, you do NOT unset the memory limit, the only thing it achieves is exactly what it did.

There's a problem with the S3 uploader; it tries to load the whole file into the memory.  Probably need to upload it in chunks, somehow.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you'll want to do is to upload a very small file. Let's say 100KB. Then a 1MB file. And so on, until the application crashes.

I know you'll prefer to use Laravel to upload the files to S3; but at this stage -depending on the file size you're uploading- you might want to use a command-line tool instead, like s3cmd. The reasoning behind this is that uploading within the webstack as you are doing is not convenient:

1-It does not scale. A file of 1MB might work, but a file of 1,00001MB might crash the application.

2-This requires you to let PHP consume a lot of memory. Therefore multiple separate processes doing the same operation might kill your web stack, generating downtime. Spinning this in a separate process -ideally with a queue- will let the system scale up.

3-In the case you insist with Laravel doing the upload, do it in such a way that it's the CLI doing the actual upload, and not the web stack. Again, use a queue for this.

As a general advice, when you find yourself increasing the memory limit to astronomic values to make your script work, it's very likely that you're doing something wrong that can be done much more effectively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not too worried about scale, it's a small application that will only be used by a handful of people. All files uploaded will be video files no larger than 100MB. The Storage facade should be working, so I want to figure out what's wrong and fix it rather than find a work around.